# how to get the first numeric sequence in a string?

Tags: javascript

The input variable contains one or more numeric strings in its character set, not having a fixed size and can have space between letters and numbers. In both cases, I need to identify only the first numerical sequence that appears in the string (it will never be separated by a space). Some examples of the input string:

```
"a12bcde097fg"  >> return 12
"120abc198672f" >> return 120
"a052bcd123fg"  >> return 052
"a 52 - bcd12"  >> return 52
"A b 123 cd 1"  >> return 123
```

Is there a way to do this with a single command and be effective in all situations?

Comment: basic reg expression

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what research you have done and any attempts you've made to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: In the meantime, some well-meaning people will post answers because this is a simple task and they can show off their prowess. Their answers do not serve the mission of Stack Overflow, which is to create a knowledge base of high-quality questions and answers.

Answer (score 3):

You could match only digits without global flag.

```js
const 
    getFirstDigits = string => string.match(/\d+/)?.[0] || '',
    array = ["a12bcde097fg", "120abc198672f", "a052bcd123fg", "a 52 - bcd12", "A b 123 cd 1", "a"],
    result = array.map(getFirstDigits);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const s = "a12bcde097fg";
const r = /(\d+)/.exec(s);
if (r[0]) {
    console.log(r[0]); 
}
```